# Android device appears offline despite plugging in USB and switching on USB debugging

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to run my Android app on a Samsung Galaxy Ace. Despite plugging in the USB and enabling debugging, when I try to run the app, Eclipse prints out a message saying

```
[2012-07-14 22:56:19 - Cricket] Android Launch!
[2012-07-14 22:56:19 - Cricket] adb is running normally.
[2012-07-14 22:56:19 - Cricket] Performing nikhil.android.cricket.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-07-14 22:56:19 - Cricket] No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration                     after connecting a device or starting an AVD.
```

I'd like to add that I've been trying a lot but am unable to do anything. I tried killing adb and restarting it. Same error. Also, I am able to run it instantly when I connect my friend's Samsung Galaxy Note. But it won't run on  my Samsung Galaxy Ace. I'd appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: What does 'adb devices' list?   The Ace normally runs Android 2.2 which being rather old might not be compatible with the application you built (I forget if compatibility gets checked or not in this case)

Comment: adb lists the Galaxy Ace device 15 times. The first 14 times it shows the device as 'offline' The last time, it says 'online'. Oh, and I am running 2.3.3 which is supported by the application I am trying to run.

Comment: Would that be an unofficial build?

Comment: I can't believe it's written "AVD's", I guess I need to call the apostrophe police.

Comment: Restart Device worked for me...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Go to DDMS in Eclipse IDE.

[image]

There is one menu: Expand that menu and select the *Reset adb* option.

[image]

Wait for a few seconds, it will reset your selected ADB device.

Comment: Excellent!!! Thank you very very much! Can't believe I struggled so much with this simple thing.

Answer (score 5):

Just reboot the phone, it will solve your issue. no need to adb restart is required.

Answer (score 1):

To install the Android USB driver on Windows 7 for the first time:

1. Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
2. Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
3. Select Devices in the left pane.
4. Locate and expand Other device in the right pane.
5. Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select Update Driver Software. This      will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
6. Select Browse my computer for driver software and click Next.
7. Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
8. Click Next to install the driver.
   Or, to upgrade an existing Android USB driver on Windows 7 with the new driver:

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem with Samsung Google nexus. I use Mac and I followed these steps to solve my problem

If you are developing on eclipse skip step 2

1: Enable USB debugging on your phone.
   for lesser than 3.2 version go to Settings->Applications-> development
   for versions 4.0 and higher its in Settings->development
   for 4.2 its hidden. Go to Settings->about phone and tap build number 7 times (message will appear that you are a developer now)

2: In your manifest file add android:debuggable="true" to the application element

Answer (score 1):

You might have to change the active *USB computer connection* setting. I had the same problem while running a Beanstalk custom rom based on Android 4.3. It was solved by switching from the default *Media device (MTP)* to *Mass storage*. The device was then automatically recognized by eclipse.

Comment: Very useful answer I've got a Samsung Galaxy S5 and once I change this setting it worked.  Thank you.  The phone will ask you to accept a Key from the computer (Mac) connected to it, and afterward it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Windows:

<kbd>Start Menu button</kbd> > *type:* cmd

**Problem**, the device is offline:

`adb devices`

> `List of devices attached`
>   `07952b41`**offline**

1. `adb kill-server`
2. `adb start-server` *(Wait some seconds ...)*
3. `adb devices`

> `List of devices attached`
>   `07952b41`**device**

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything in this list to no avail, with a Samsung galaxy 5 (4.4.2).  The only way I got it to work finally was to select the option to "revoke USB debugging authorization" which caused my phone to prompt me to authorize my computer to debug with it -- only then did it appear "online."

Installing the newer newer google / samsung drivers with the enhanced usb debugging security seems not to trigger an authorization prompt by itself.  Seems you need to help it along by revoking all previous authorizations even on a new phone.

Comment: Tried everything and this worked! With the cable plugged in, I actually turned off USB debugging, then turned it back on and when I did it asked me to authorize. i did and whalla!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my new updated to Kitkat GT-N7100. I tried everything

- unhidden developer menu & enable USB debugging
- reset ADB
- installing latest USB device driver
- installing laest KIES

none worked.

Device always looked offline in ddms.

If you tried all this and still no use then try this:

http://www.droidextra.org/2013/12/24/solved-fix-adb-devices-offline-100-working.html

It worked for me.

Akif,

Answer (score 0):

if **your Samsung mobile driver not install successfully** then also this problem may occur

so download driver from following link and install it in your PC [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=961956)

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml, see that your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion match your device.

Answer (score 0):

There may be no problem with Eclipse.  Try running adb shell and see if it connects to your device.  If it doesn't, this may signal any number of problems: with your USB port (try a different one and/or unplugging other peripherals), with your OS (try restarting), with your USB cable (try a different one), or the phone (try rebooting it or try a different one).

Eclipse is only the last link in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with my HTC phone, which works well with other app until I use the android google play services for maps v2. You may find the link below for how to install the sample.

http://nlabs.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/the_maps_sample_from_google_play_services/

I tried the suggestions made in this thread with no progress.

I then found my error that I did not overwrite the default setting below, but instead I add my entries. So I made the correct, and still got the same error.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="inter your code" />
```

I then run the debug mode. It worked. Once at the HTC, I was prompted to install the 'Google Play Services', which is expected and install works.

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing change you minsdkVersion to 8,in your manifest file it surely works....

```
> android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "reset ADB". After that your device may ask

> Allow USB debugging?

On that screen, checking

> always allow from this computer

may resolve your problems in the future for that device and computer.
See more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16224992/143808

Answer (score 0):

1. First download the USB driver for your android phone from their respective site. *For samsung phone you can use [this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=961956).*
2. Click on reset abd.
3. Reboot your phone.

This worked for me when I encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

using newest adb helped, thanks Akif. use kill-server and then start-server with newest adb. also it will fix some other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Window Task Manager` and and `close adb.exe`. Resolve my issue. And also **reset USB Debugging**.

Answer (score -3):

No need of doing this all .

Just restore your pc to earlier time .
it is on control panel,system and security.