# android usb debug not working - Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried different solutions proposed here in StackOverFlow but unfortunatly doesn't work any of that idea/suggestion.(for example: [Android 4.2.2 USB debugging "Always allow from this computer" option result in target unknown for device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053463/android-4-2-2-usb-debugging-always-allow-from-this-computer-option-result-in-t/47889056#47889056))

I have macbook with the new Android Studio 3.0.1 and I'm trying to connect my device Huawei P10 in developer mode.

The device is somenthing receiving the RSA fingerprint from my Mac but if I do "Always allow from this computer" is still showing and not "trusting" the device.

I tried to restart adb and clean the .android/adbkey* files but not working.

Using another device Huawei Honor it's working fine.

Can you please help me to fix?

thanks

UPDATE:
when I do enable USB debug I see logs moving but finishing in offline the device and this is the most recurrent message:
G.ContextMap:Context not found for ID

UPDATE 2:
12-21 10:15:57.037 4859-19947/? E/Bth: BtOppRfcommListener:Error accept connection java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
12-21 10:15:57.369 1038-1038/? I/TrafficMonitor: expired arrive. level:-1
12-21 10:15:57.369 1038-1038/? I/TrafficMonitor: during_ms:2006,period_ms:2000
12-21 10:15:57.369 1038-1038/? I/TrafficMonitor: count:233,rx_sum:0,tx_sum:0,rxBytes:0,during_ms:2006,rx_speed:0.0,tx_speed:0.0,rto:0.0
12-21 10:15:57.539 4859-19947/? E/Bth: BtOppRfcommListener:Error accept connection java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
12-21 10:15:57.660 1641-1641/? I/NetworkSpeedManagerEx: mIsStop = false
12-21 10:15:57.666 1641-1641/? I/NetworkSpeedManagerEx: value=0.0speed = 0K/s
12-21 10:15:57.666 1641-1641/? I/NetworkSpeedView: /update(), speed=0K/s parent class:class com.android.systemui.statusbar.HwSystemIcons
12-21 10:15:57.694 1641-1641/? I/NetworkSpeedManagerEx: mIsStop = false
12-21 10:15:57.700 1641-1641/? I/NetworkSpeedManagerEx: value=0.0speed = 0K/s
12-21 10:15:57.701 1641-1641/? I/NetworkSpeedView: /update(), speed=0K/s parent class:class com.android.systemui.statusbar.HwSystemIcons
12-21 10:15:58.040 4859-19947/? E/Bth: BtOppRfcommListener:Error accept connection java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Comment: The ADB process it's automatically initialized by Studio...

Comment: If you hit build 7 times you get into developer mode(sounds like you did this) Settings>Developer Options> USB debugging on. Can you see the device as a network device? TCP/IP utilities allow you to ping the IP address if you know it.

Comment: It's already enabled... Problem is that sometime is going offline. Same procedure as you did was done on different phone and works...

Comment: 12-21 09:04:34.968 4859-5021/? I/bt_btm: BTM_InqDbRead: bd addr [c48e8fd4ea12]
12-21 09:04:34.969 4859-4907/? W/bt_btif: HAL bt_gatt_callbacks->client->scan_result_cb
12-21 09:04:34.969 4859-4907/? E/Bth: G.ContextMap:Context not found for ID 10
                                      
                                      [ 12-21 09:04:36.394   538:  538 E/         ]
                                      [E/basp_control] input param invalid!
12-21 09:04:36.403 1641-1641/? W/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED AMP: 0; Volt: 0

Comment: installed different android version same issue. using another device still running. i guess i somenthing on the phone now...

Comment: Can you step through with debugger and isolate problem? Can you post some code?

Comment: there isn't problem with code, because is still before deploying somenthing to the device. Anyway the same project,computer, android studio is not working for my huawei p10 but working with a samsung j6 or huawei honor 7 (it's connecting/deploying/working without any issue)

Comment: tried also now to delete cache and remove data to the Settings application into the application menu panel... and reenable the developer debug...restart adb .... same issue the device is not found or is offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally fixed. checking on internet I wasn't the only one had that issue on P10 and P10plus or P9lite. you need to: 1) have a good and original hi quality usb cable 2) set into the setting the USB configuration into RNDIS(USB Ethernet) that's fixed

Answer (score 1):

It seems you only enabled Developer Options but did not enable USB debugging.

Please go to setting and check USB debugging option in Developer Options.

Comment: It's enabled... I did the same... Sometime is finding... Asking the authorization... But after is going offline

Comment: finally fixed.

checking on internet I wasn't the only one had that issue on P10 and P10plus or P9lite.

you need to:

1) have a good and original hi quality usb cable

2) set into the setting the USB configuration into RNDIS(USB Ethernet)

that's fixed to me

ciao